# Application freezes when I try to get content of URL

Tags: c#, http

First see my Source Code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String url = "http://localhost";
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
try
{
    Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
    if (data == null)
        throw new WebException("Cannot browse the url...");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    textBox1.Text = s;
    data.Close();
    reader.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

When I run my application, It will freeze in the duration of this operation.
Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: Define "freeze"? Are you referring to how the program method blocks until .ReadToEnd() returns? Is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which part of my code is wrong?

The part where you perform a blocking network operation in your UI thread. While your UI thread is blocked waiting for the response, the controls can't repaint and your UI can't respond to events.

You should do this in a background thread and then use [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) (WinForms) or [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) (WPF) to marshal a call back to the UI thread. See [Joe Albahari's threading guide](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Rich_Client_Applications) for more information.

Alternatively, use the async operations on `WebClient`.

Comment: Tnx a lot. sorry, can you explain more about "Alternatively, use the async operations on WebClient" , please?

Comment: @Programmersinan: I don't have time right now, but look at `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` for starters...

Answer (score 2):

Does it ever return? I'm sure it probably does as `OpenRead` will throw an exception if passed an invalid URI.  From the docs:

> The OpenRead method creates a Stream instance used to read the contents of the resource specified by the address parameter. **This method blocks while opening the stream**. To continue executing while waiting for the stream, use one of the OpenReadAsync methods.

`OpenRead` is synchronous, i.e., it blocks the current thread until it returns with all of the data.  if you wish to perform the read asynchronously use [`OpenReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted.aspx).

When you call this method the operation will *begin*, but your code will continue on.  When the operation completes a callback method will be invoked (the handler for its [`OpenReadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted.aspx) event) which will handle the response.